# Xamlreader/writer custom serialisation (dictionary)

Tags: wpf, xaml, serialization

I'd like to (de)serialize a dictionary collection object with xamlreader and xamlwriter. This is not supported by default in the framework.

Does anyone know how to adapt the following code from https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-serializedeserialize-a-dictionary-object-in-1 designed for the xmlreader to work with the xamlreader?

```
[XmlRoot("Languages")]
public class LanguageSettings<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
                                              IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if(reader.IsEmptyElement) { return; }
        reader.Read();
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            object key = reader.GetAttribute("Title");
            object value = reader.GetAttribute("Value");
            this.Add((TKey)key, (TValue)value);
            reader.Read();
        }
    }
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Language");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Title", key.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", this[key].ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

This is required for the purpose of serializing a WPF object inherited from a Content into that has a Generic.Dictionary object as a member variable (doing XamlWriter.Save(wpfObject.dictionaryObj) throws an exception that generics are not supported).

Comment: Why would you want to use XamlReader/Write for ordinary XML? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to serialize a wpf object that has a dictionary member variable